# Visual Studio 2015 Upadate 3 not working with EF for Oracle?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

I have been using VS Update 2 with Oracle Entity Framework for a while now. I decided to update to the VS Update 3 and now my Oracle EF no longer works.

I'm trying to add it to a new project and when I go to Add | New Item | Data Item it no longer sees my DB connection. When I click on the New Connection button I only saw drivers for MS SQL Server.

I then downloaded and reinstalled the latest version of Oracle Developer Tools for VS. I then uninstalled/installed Oracle Managed Data and Oracle EF through NuGet. Now when I try to click on the New Connection button I get an error "An unexpected error occurred in the ODP Managed Provider for .Net". I've done the reinstall a couple different times, restarted VS, and even rebooted my machine with no luck.

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can get Oracle EF back to working with VS?

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would leave a little information here in case it helps someone else.

Part of the fix was reinstalling Oracle for Visual Studio. However, you can't just do a repair on it. Once I did a full uninstall, reboot, and then re-install it seemed to come back. After that I did have to another error about an object not set to an instance of an object but I used the following link that suggested renaming the Visual Studio and Visual Studio Common folder as well as running the `devenv /resetuserdata`.

[Visual Studio 2015 error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" after install of ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (RC1 Update 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084003/visual-studio-2015-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object)

Repairing VS 2015 didn't seem to help. I also tried removing the