# error while trying to load visual studio project on Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, csproj

I'm running visual studio on mac and when trying to load a project created on a windows VS I'm getting the following error:

> Error while trying to load project
>   '/Volumes/Storage/LocalStorage/Projects/WebDev/engage-api/Engage.DataAccess/Engage.DataAccess.csproj':
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object

[image: visual studio error screenshot]

The most similar issue I could find on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084003/visual-studio-2015-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object)) has a solution that is windows specific. It essentially says to clear the VS cache. I'd like to do the same thing for my issue but I can't find the VS cache on my Mac machine.

#### The Question

Where are the VS cache files on Mac so I can delete them?
**OR** any other solutions to this error?

#### What I've Done

Not much...not that I haven't tried but haven't found any solutions to try. I looked through `~/Library` and the Visual Studio application content files for any obvious cache files but could not spot any I felt comfortable deleting.