# C# - Reporting Services (rdlc) - Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I'm quite new in using **Reporting Services**, and I'm currently facing this problem:

I have two report files (.rdlc). One of them was made by one partner of mine in my entreprise, the other by me. I want to Add a new Dataset to my report, so I can use it in a Tablix. The *Data source* is correct, but in the *Available datasets* dropdown, the object I want **(Indicator4Report)** is not present [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXMqM.png):

[image: Available datasets not showing Indicator4Report]

If I press the *New...* button, and then the *Object* button, I can find the object I want to add as dataset [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3y7Y.png):

[image: Object I want to add]

But clicking it shows this error: `object reference not set to an instance of an object` [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7QB7.png)

[image: Object reference not set to an instance of an object error]

The object is declared in the file `Foo.Weee.Logic.ViewModels.Advisor`, which looks like this:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Foo.Weee.Logic.ViewModels.Advisor
{
    public class ResultsSummary
    {
       public string blabla {get;set;}
       ...more attributes...
    }

    ...more objects...

    public class ResultsSummary4Report
    {
        public ResultsSummary4Report(ResultsSummary results)
        {
            this.blabla = results.blabla;
            ...more code...
            this.indicatorBlabla = new Indicator4Report[] //The object I want
            {
                new Indicator4Report() { title = "Profesional Independiente", value = 7.5f , color1 = "red", color2 = "gray" }
            };
            ...more code...
        }

        public string blabla {get;set;}

        ...more attributes...

        public Indicator4Report[] indicatorBlabla {get;set;} //The object I want

        ...more attributes...
   }

   ...more objects...

   /* The object I want */
   public class Indicator4Report
   {
      public string title { get; set; }
      public float value { get; set; }
      public string color1 { get; set; }
      public string color2 { get; set; }
   }
}
```

As I said, I'm new to this, so maybe it is a dumb mistake or something I'm doing wrong, but I don't know how to tackle the problem.

Thank you very much for your help, and if you need more info, code or screenshots, feel free to ask.

PS: I'm using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: I've tried each of the solutions here, with a class that's part of the same app, and in a different project, and I just cannot resolve it at all.  :-(

Comment: Sometimes it's a [cache problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084003/visual-studio-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-after).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.

As I have the Reports and the `Foo.Weee.Logic.Advisor`file in different projects, I had to add a link to that file in the Report project (*Right button* -> *Add* -> *Existing Item...* -> *Add As Link*).

After doing that, I could happily use the object I wanted as Data source without errors.

Comment: can you clarify what does you mean by adding the existing  Item as link? when I do that, VS creates a new file in the target project

Answer (score 0):

For me, it turns out all the projects have be built with Any CPU or it won't work. If you force x64, the designer can't read that and it crashes!  Also, make sure all the classes are marked as [Serializable] or you might have problems, too.

Answer (score -1):

i got the same problem in my rdlc report. what i did to solve this is just simply deleted my dataset and add the same dataset of my report. this problem occured in my situation due to some modification in web.config file. hope it will help you