# cppcheck plugin issue with visual studio 2017 "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cppcheck

I am trying to use cppcheck plugin with visual studio 2017. However when I select tools/Check current project with cppcheck, it always says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Any suggestions?

I am using

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017, Version 15.7.6
- CPPCheckPlugin 1.3.5
- CMake 3.12.1
- Windows 10 Pro 64bit

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should provide us with more details about your problem. Actually, it's really hard for someone to answer. Such lack of details can get your question closed.

Comment: @Macmade Thank you for your comments. Can you be more specific on what details are needed? My pc hardware information? Or a piece of example code? A screenshot of the error message? I am using windows 10 (64bit) by the way.

Comment: By the way, I have tried the first solution in http://stackoverflow.com/a/34085345/4275342. It doesn't help.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I just right click on the cpp file or the project and select cppcheck, and this popup message shows up.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the problem was resolved after I edited the projects and checked "Enable Code Analysis on Build". I was then able to uncheck this option, but it leaves

```
<RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>
```

in the vcxproj file, which seems to resolve the problem.