# Can't create C++ Projects in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Everytime I try to create a C++ Project it just gives me an error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".
I tried reinstalling my visual studio, repairing it, clearing the registry, going on and manually deleting the folders. No changes.

My question is how to fix this issue as it's really irritating and I truly have no idea what's causing it.

Comment: Did you try the answers here ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084003/visual-studio-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-after

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" after install of ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084003/visual-studio-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-after)

Comment: @tambre Nope, I tried everything nothing works.