# Visual Studio 2019, Publish to Azure is failed for NodeJs Web App

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2019

Node Js publish from Visual Studio 2019 stopped working. there was no update on VS or code configurations.

[image]

**Error dump from temp file**:

```
27-Nov-20 09:58:33
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.CanShowRestoreAction()
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.RebuildCrudProfileCommands(IProfileVisual profile)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.set_SelectedProfile(IProfileVisual value)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.Initialize(ProfileSelectorUserControl view)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Provider.DefaultPublishTabProvider.<CreateViewAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Provider.PublishProjectDesignerTabProvider.<CreateViewAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
===================
```

What I tried:

1. Clearing .vs, data, bin
2. Clearing temp
   But nothing worked.

Anyway to resolve this?

Workaround: Using [Deployment center local git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-local-git)

Comment: Are you still able to build and run your app locally without any errors?

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara, yes build and local run is has no issues. Even the workaround I added works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, emptying the `C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio` and `C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon` folders should fix your publish error. If not, try repairing your VS installation or re-installing the latest version available.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084003/visual-studio-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-after) highlights a few other workarounds to try. If the problem still persists, please report it on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) so the VS Team can investigate further.