# Error in Configuring .net web application project(.net framework), while creating a new project in Visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-framework-version

## [error is Operation is not valid due to current state of object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK8QC.png)

it shouldn't be show this error, I don't know how to figure out this..I checked every where not able to what issue is, may be the visual studio 2022 erro or the error while creating the new project of dotnet web application

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you, you can mark it (click the check mark to the left of the answer) so that it can help more people

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

Delete the contents from the following folders:

`C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio`

`C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon`

Sometimes, you need to go to:

`[x64] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`

`[x86] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`

and run `devenv /resetuserdata`.

Expect, that all of your user settings such as Visual Studio layout, linked Microsoft account or start page might disappear.

Reference from: [Visual Studio error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" after install of ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084003/visual-studio-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-after).

There are many answers in this link that are of reference value

If the answers in this link still cannot solve your issue, it is recommended that you use Visual Studio Installer to repair or update Visual Studio.